# OnTextChanged does not trigger after required attribute validation

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an update Panel with some textbox and I'm trying to replace the requiredfieldvalidators by using the required attribute on the textboxes which makes everything much cleaner. Only first textbox has required for testing purposes.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 8px;">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="float: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblRefCliente" runat="server" Text="Referência Cliente " ForeColor="#142658" Style="font-weight: bold;"></asp:Label><span style="color: red;">* </span>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRefClient" CssClass="txtStyle" runat="server" required></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvRefClient" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ControlToValidate="txtRefClient" ErrorMessage=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                            <td style="float: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblRefInterna" runat="server" Text="Referência Interna " ForeColor="#142658" Style="font-weight: bold;"></asp:Label><span style="color: red;">* </span>
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRefInterna" CssClass="txtStyle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvRefInterna" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ControlToValidate="txtRefInterna" ErrorMessage=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="float: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblIndice" runat="server" Text="Indíce " ForeColor="#142658" Style="font-weight: bold;"></asp:Label><span style="color: red;">* </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtIndice" CssClass="txtStyle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvIndice" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ControlToValidate="txtIndice" ErrorMessage=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                            <td style="float: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblProject" runat="server" Text="Projecto " ForeColor="#142658" Style="font-weight: bold;"></asp:Label><span style="color: red;">* </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtProject" CssClass="txtStyle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvProject" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ControlToValidate="txtProject" ErrorMessage=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="float: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCadMensal" runat="server" Text="Cadência Mensal " ForeColor="#142658" Style="font-weight: bold;"></asp:Label><span style="color: red;">* </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCadMensal" CssClass="txtStyle" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtCadMensal_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvCadMensal" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ControlToValidate="txtCadMensal" ErrorMessage=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>                                    
                            </td>
                            <td style="float: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDesenho" runat="server" Text="Desenho " ForeColor="#142658" Style="font-weight: bold;"></asp:Label><span style="color: red;">* </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesenho" CssClass="txtStyle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDesenho" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ControlToValidate="txtDesenho" ErrorMessage=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="float: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNumCOMDEV" runat="server" Text="Nº de COMDEV " ForeColor="#142658" Style="font-weight: bold;"></asp:Label><span style="color: red;">* </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumCOMDEV" CssClass="txtStyle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNumCOMDEV" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ControlToValidate="txtNumCOMDEV" ErrorMessage=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                            <td style="float: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblNumFormas" runat="server" Text="Nº Formas de Lançamento " ForeColor="#142658" Style="font-weight: bold;"></asp:Label><span style="color: red;">* </span>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumFormas" CssClass="txtStyle" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtNumFormas_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvNumFormas" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ControlToValidate="txtNumFormas" ErrorMessage=""></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="float: right;">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCapacidadeReal" runat="server" Text="Capacidade Real(métodos) " ForeColor="#142658" Style="font-weight: bold;"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCapacidadeReal" CssClass="txtStyle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now the problem is that i Have this textbox txtNumComps that creates some dynamic textboxes for some input and does it OnTextChanged event and is doing it asynch. The problem is that when the validation from the required attribute fires, the OnTextChanged does not trigger, only triggers the 2nd i write something. I don't see what can cause this problem. if someone could help i'd appreciate.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="NumComps">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblNumComps" runat="server" Text="Nº de Componentes " ForeColor="#142658" Style="font-weight: bold;"></asp:Label><span style="color: red; margin-right: 5px;"> * </span>
                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumComps" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtNumComps_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvNumComps" runat="server" ForeColor="red" ErrorMessage="" ControlToValidate="txtNumComps" ClientValidationFunction="NumpCompsValidator"></asp:CustomValidator>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="txtNumComps" EventName="TextChanged" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: It is expected that `OnTextChanged` event triggers when text changes in the `TextBox`. What should be your expected output?

Comment: Once text is typed into the txtNumComps, it generates a number of rows with 3 Textboxes based on the number typed and it generates Async when the even triggers, but if I press submit button while having a textbox with the "required" attribute empty, it triggers the validation event and if i try to type on the txtNumComps, it won't trigger the OnTextChanged event after losing focus on textbox. Something from the required attribute makes it unable to trigger OnTextChanged events once the validation is triggered